# Setting a US country filter in Google Analytics gives an error that the filter won't change the data

Tags: google-analytics, filtering

I have created a filter in Analytics to include only the details of traffic from United States.

[image]

Please correct me if I am doing wrong,  Because on verifying the filter it throws me this error:

> This filter would not have changed your data. Either the filter configuration is incorrect, or the set of sampled data is too small.

Comment: Aren't you better of creating a segment on your default view?

Comment: I want to give limited access i.e. only the access to filtered data to some specific users. So I opted to create a new view.